# Determining Win Percentage from skill level

Tags: math, probability

I am making a program in which two players face each other in "combat", each player have a skill level, represented by a number between 1 and 100, this number is used to determine which player is better so for example if player A has 50 and player B has 100 then B has 50% more chances of winning the combat, What would be a good way of getting this number knowing the skill level of both players?

I tried different ways, for example adding both skill levels and throwing a selecting a random number in this range if the number is less than a player skill then he wins however i am not sure if this is a good way, I think the probability is off. I also tried to use rules, for example if they have the same skill then is 50% (anyone can win) if one is half the other then is 25% chances for the lower player and so on but this gets complicated fast. Any pointers on how to do this calculation?

Thank you in advance for your help

-hei

Comment: You're asking specifically about what to do when the users have *equal* skill level?

Comment: @Cody Gray - No, i'm asking about a way to get the chances for a player to win, knowing his and his opponent skill level. If they have equal skill level it would be 50% chances for any of them. Edit spelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if player A has 50 and player B has 100 then B has 50% more chances of winning the combat

If you mean that player B should win twice as often, then this works:

```
r = random(1, A+B)
if r <= A
  winner = 'A'
else
  winner = 'B'
```

Winner A will win 50/150 or 1/3 of the time. Winner B will win 2/3 of the time (twice as much).

Maybe you mean for the distance to be the weight. E.g., 10 vs 5 should have a 5% advantage.

Then you could try (assuming `B >= A`):

```
r = random(1, 200 + B - A)
if r <= 100 
  winner = 'A'
else
  winner = 'B'
```

So if `A == B` then chances are even.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was trying to see the problem with probability but the way you explain it makes more sense, I was confusing 50% (1/2) with B wins twice as much (1/3 and 2/3) also I need to polish my math skills, by the way is that python or just pseudocode?

Comment: oh did not see your edit, I am a little confuse with your second solution would you mind explain it a little bit please? thanks

Comment: It is just psuedocode. With the first version 1 vs 2 and 50 vs 100 is the same thing. B will win twice as much. With the second version, the distance between A and B determines the probability. 5 vs 10 is a difference of 5. So for every win by A, you can expect B to win 1.05 times (5% more). 50 vs 100 is a difference of 50, so for every win by A, you can expect 1.5 wins by B (50% more).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, its more clear now, I think the first solution apply better to my problem. The second solution seems to indicate a change in the difficulty of the game as the player advance.